# Evaluating list of XPATH expressions stored in a set, in scala

Tags: xml, scala, xpath

I am trying to evaluate a list of XPATH expressions stored in a Collection using scala, but i am not getting any output.

Here is an example

```
val jokesXML = <jokes> <pun rating="fine"> <question> Q: Why ? </question> <answer>A: Because</answer>  </pun> </jokes>

//this works
val x1 = "pun"
jokesXML\\{x1}

//this works
jokesXML\\ "pun" \ "question"

// this doesnt work
val x2 = """"pun" \ "question""""
jokesXML\\{x2}
```

The question is why x2 is not getting evaluated in the same way as the line above. xpath expressions get evaluated when they are expressed in a literal way eg `weather \ "channel" \ "item" \ "forecast" \ "@date"`
How to move this expression into a variable and make it work the same way?

Comment: So... What is your question?

Comment: @zx485 sorry if it want clear, question is why x2 is not getting evaluated in the same way as the line above. xpath expressions get evaluated when they are expressed in a literal way eg `weather \ "channel" \ "item" \ "forecast" \ "@date"` How to move this expression into a variable and make it work the same way?

Comment: No need to apologize. But incorporating this comment into your question would seriously improve it and therefore the chance of a good answer. --- Just edit your question! That's all!